# Restrict AWS IOT Device to it's self with policy

Tags: aws-iot

Looking to limit a device to just it's resources (shadow) inside of AWS IOT, based upon the certificate it uses to authenticate.

Device1 is attached to Cert1 - I want to have a generic policy that would only let Device1 update the shadow of Device 1 and not Device2

but all being triggered off the cert the devices uses to authenticate with.

The policy below doesn't seem to work - any help?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached": [
            "true"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxxxx:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingTypeName}/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxxxx:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingTypeName}/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxxxx:topicfilter/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingTypeName}/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxxxx:topicfilter/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingTypeName}/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There's hardly any information about how it doesn't work other than the title of the question. Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: Looking to limit a device to just it's resources (shadow) inside of AWS IOT, based upon the certificate it uses to authenticate.

Device1 is attached to Cert1 - want to have a generic policy that would only let Device1 update the shadow of Device 1 and not Device2 

but all being triggered off the cert!

Answer (score 5):

This is what I ended up using, to limit the device to it's own resources and have the ClientID be the name of the AWS Thing as well

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached": [
            "true"
          ]
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
          "iot:ClientId": [
            "${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxx:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxx:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxx:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, suppose I have 5 devices registered on aws iot and I want only those 5 to be used. Can I put this condition "Bool": {
          "iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached": [
            "true"
          ] and use wildcard topic name? Will it ensure only those 5 devices will be allowed?